# How to set ComboBox DataSource properly?

Tags: c#, list, combobox

I'm trying to set List as DataSource for ComboBox. User atributes are saved in .txt file in format: username;password;isAdministrator. Referring to MSDN I did everything right.

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
    public ComboBoxForm()
    {
        string path = "data\\usr.txt";
        string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        for(int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] atributes = rows[i].Split(';');
            User u = new User(atributes[0], atributes[1], atributes[2]);
            users.Add(u);
        }
            comboBox1.DataSource = users;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

However everytime I run the app, it crashes with NullReferrenceException. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you post your stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `InitializeComponent` at the start of the constructor, otherwise `comboBox1` will be `null`.  `comboBox1` is created inside `InitializeComponent`:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ...
    this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
    ...
```